# Composer version of archive-dump?

Tags: 8

It appears that some things have changed with Drush. I have a project that is reactivated, and we did updates, but somewhere along the way that file is lost. Before solving some fatal error glitches, I need to try and create another backup, but that glitch is preventing me from getting to the admin page to do an export. (/admin/config/development/configuration/full/export)

I need to solve some fatal errors I'm getting, but before I go any further, I'd really like to create a tar of what I've got, and it no longer seems possible.

Is there a way to create a tar of the site from composer? If so, what is it?

Comment: `tar -cvzf myball.tar.gz some-dir/`? I don't believe Composer has something like that built-in. Unfortunately the rest of your question is really vague.

Comment: Yeah, just use the tar function.